# React code is somehow executing backwards. I'm about to go crazy

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs

Seriously, this is like the double slit experiment of Javascript.

Basically what I have is a series of steps. What I want to happen is that when a user adds a new step to the list, the state for `activeStepId` gets set to be the newly added step (it gets highlighted in the list of steps).

As you'll see below, I'm listening to changes in my store and triggering the onChange event in the component.

Now, here's the crazy part:

Whenever I do the comparison `newState.steps.length > this.state.steps.length` to see if the new state has more steps than the previous state, somehow the old state has already been updated to the new state, despite the fact that setState hasn't even been called yet!

Now, I know you're probably thinking there's some other place in my code where I'm updating the state without realizing it. Yeah, I thought that too, but when I removed the call to setState below and then inspected the result, it worked! `this.state.steps.length` was what it should have been: the old value, not the new one.

I've spent hours on this at this point, and I have literally not a clue what's going on.

```
  componentDidMount: function(){
    FlowStepStore.on('change', this.onChange);
  },

  onChange: function(){
    var newState = this.getState();

    // If we've just added a step, set it as active
    if(newState.steps.length > this.state.steps.length){
      newState.activeStepId = newState.steps[newState.steps.length - 1].id;
    }

    this.setState(newState);
  },

  getState: function(){
    return {
      activeStepId: this.activeStepId(),
      steps: FlowStepStore.getSteps()
    };
  },
```

I also tried doing it a different way, performing the step count comparison by using componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) and comparing prevState against this.state, but I had the exact same problem! Somehow, prevState already equals the current state.

Mind blown.

Help!

Comment: what have you done to debug this? Are you using breakpoints? It seems like the assignment is happening before you compare the lengths, so the code with the problem will be earlier than the code here. Breakpoints and debugging are explained at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/debugging/info

Comment: Since this.state.steps contains a reference to the array in FlowStepStore, you have to make sure you do not mutate this reference, but rather create a new array. Is this the case?

Comment: @Mousey I've debugged every way I can think of. If you do a `console.log(this.state.steps.length); console.log(newState.steps.length);` and put it at the very top of the onChange function, you get the same value for both, which means that somehow the state is already updated at the very beginning of that function. BUT, if you remove the call to `this.setState` at the END of the `onChange` function, then `this.state.steps.length` is 1 less than `newState.steps.length` as it should be. Even crazier, if you put a debug; statement before `setState`, the values are updated before it even gets there

Comment: @Heap you're a genius. I didn't realize my state had a direct reference to a variable in the store, which was getting updated prior to setting the component state. Modified it to return _steps.slice() instead of just _steps and now it works! Thank you for saving me hours and hours of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Heap's comment was correct. I didn't realize my state had a direct reference to a variable in the store (JS passes by reference, not by value), which was getting updated prior to setting the component state. Modified my store to return _steps.slice() instead of just _steps and now it works!